# Заголовочный файл для структур C++

Tags: c++, c++11

Как создать правильно создать заголовочный файл для структур?
Пытаюсь так, не выходит:
**structures.h**

```
#ifndef LAB_8_STRUCTURES_H
#define LAB_8_STRUCTURES_H

struct Date;

struct Product;

#endif //LAB_8_STRUCTURES_H
```

**structures.cpp**

```
#include "structures.h"

struct Date {
    int day;
    int mon;
    int year;

    void init(int day, int mon, int year) {
        this->day = day;
        this->mon = mon;
        this->year = year;
    }

    long getDays() {
        int m[] = {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};

        long days = (year - 1) * 365 + (year - 1) % 4;
        for (int i = 0; i < mon; i++) {
            days += m[i];
        }
        if (mon >= 1)
            days++;
        days += day;

        return days;
    }
};

struct Product {
    char *name;
    float weight;
    float price;
    Date exp;

    void init(char *name, float weight, float price, Date exp) {
        this->name = name;
        this->weight = weight;
        this->price = price;
        this->exp = exp;
    }
};

#endif
```

Comment: А что именно у вас и откуда _не выходит_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так, как написано у вас - все функции-члены определены в самом объявлении структур (т.е. являются inline) - все это и должно быть в заголовочном файле. Просто вместо

```
struct Date;
struct Product;
```

внесите в заголовочный файл все то, что идет после

```
#include "structures.h"
```

в `structures.cpp` - и пользуйтесь.

Вот если бы у вас в объявлении структуры было

```
struct Date {
    int day;
    int mon;
    int year;

    void init(int day, int mon, int year);
    long getDays();
};
```

то это объявление должно было бы находиться в заголовочном файле, а в `.cpp`-файле - реализация:

```
void Date::init(int day, int mon, int year) {
    this->day = day;
    this->mon = mon;
    this->year = year;
}

long Date::getDays() {
    int m[] = {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};

    long days = (year - 1) * 365 + (year - 1) % 4;
    for (int i = 0; i < mon; i++) {
        days += m[i];
    }
    if (mon >= 1)
        days++;
    days += day;

    return days;
}
```

Comment: Так как от автора текста ошибки не дождался, то было бы неплохо упомянуть. что это `aggregate ... has incomplete type and cannot be defined` для g++, а то по коду будет трудновато найти решение, если у кого-нибудь возникнет похожий вопрос. В VC++ не знаю как звучит ошибка.